# Changing edge arrow size in Gephi 0.9.2

Tags: networking, gephi

I'm trying to change the size of arrows so they're big enough to see easily. The slider won't let me move any more to the right and the arrows are too small at the maximum size. Is there a way to increase the size more?

Thanks for the help

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0Vwj.png)